# Sending C# struct to C++ through a socket

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, struct, byte

I want to send a struct in C# to C++ using sockets.

For example, I use this struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct pos {
    public int i;
    public float x;
};
```

If I somehow convert it into bytes and send over the network, I should be able to cast it to this in c++:

```
struct pos {
    int i;
    float x;
};
```

... I think.

1) how do you break down a struct instance in C# to send it over the network?

2) can I safely cast it to the c++ struct once I get it?

Thanks

Comment: Personally I'd be looking at known serialization rather than snagging the underlying bytes; in partiular, strings are going to be a royal pain otherwise.

Comment: I'm just going to be using floats and ints if it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The marshaller helps you with converting between .NET structs and raw bytes. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068541/how-to-convert-a-value-type-to-byte-in-c/1068585#1068585), I posted a simple solution, which boils down to `Marshal.StructureToPtr` and `Marshal.PtrToStructure`. In contrast to the more advanced solutions provided by Johann du Toit, this is in my opinion the best thing you can do if all you want to do is to push some structures through a byte stream.

If you do this, you can safely cast to the C++ struct if the length is correct, and your C++ struct is declared with the same packing as the C# struct (i.e. `#pragma pack` in VC++ or `__attribute__((packed))` in GCC).

Note that this also works with fixed length C strings, but will not take care of the endianness of larger values. I found it a simple solution to provide getters and setters for the latter problem which just swap the bytes accordingly (with `BitConverter`).

---

Some elaboration on the packing:
Take the following structure:

```
struct MyStruct {
    uint8_t a;
    float b;
};
```

With the C# declaration with StructLayout, Pack = 1, this struct will have a size of five bytes. The C++ struct, however, may have eight bytes (or even more), depending on the default packing of the compiler, who may happily insert some padding bytes to align the float value on a 32-bit boundary (just an example). Because of this, you have to apply the very same packing to both the C# and C++ struct. In Visual C++:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
// ... struct declarations...
#pragma pack(pop)
```

This means all structs declared between the two pragmas will have a packing of one. In GCC:

```
struct x {
// ...
} __attribute__((packed));
```

This will do the same. You can `#define __attribute__(x)` on Windows platforms and `#ifdef _WIN32` around the pragmas to make the code compatible with both worlds.

Comment: can you explain the last part more? I'm not sure I follow what to do there

Comment: The one about packing, or the paragraph I just added one minute ago? :)

Comment: the packaging part :p also why do you have a maxlength in your function?

Comment: I see, but if I don't mind the padding, could I just remove the Pack = 1 and then cast safely in C++?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the maxlength was about variable length structs. I also had an overload the passes `Marshal.SizeOf(value)` as maxlength :)

Comment: No, you can't just remove the Pack = 1, unless you are absolutely sure that both compilers will do exactly the same packing. You can try larger values, but the simplest thing is to just pack them tightly.

Comment: It is Visual Studio 2010 for C++/C# as compiler. Why would it be different from the compilers? Float and Int are both 4 bytes in C++/C# isn't it?

Comment: At least for int, the C++ standard does not guarantee that the length is 32 bit. Compile for x64 and you're doomed. This doesn't have to do with the packing, though, you should use fixed length types in C++ for these structs anyway (i.e. `int32_t`), which you get from including `<cstdint>`. However, the packing may actually be 8 bytes. I don't know. Try it without the packing and make a sizeof in C++ and a Marshal.SizeOf in C#, and compare the sizes. But don't be surprised when it crashes in a future version. Better make it explicit.

Comment: Ok, I am going to try it out. What does Pack = 1 do anyway? What does different values do? :p

Comment: I'm not an expert about packing, but the value is the boundary on which the members of the structure will be aligned. Specifying 1 means no padding, 2 means aligning on 16-bit-boundaries, 4 on 32-bit-boundaries. On x86 architectures, wrong alignment results only in a performance penalty, but on several architectures like ARM, you can't for example have a pointer to a wrongly-aligned value (resulting in a crash if you try). Both problems are why padding/alignment exists in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can either encode it in a format like [JSON](http://www.json.org/) (There are a lot of JSON parsers out there, check on the json.org website for a list), [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) or just roll your own. You could also try already built libraries like [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), which allows you to serialize your structures that you would create with a file in .proto format (And use [Protobuf-Net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) for C#). Another option would be [Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) which provides a way to serialize but also supplies a ready to use RCP system. It support c#, c++ and a ton of other languages by default.

So it's depends  on taste, take your pick :D

Comment: do you have to use a 3rdpart library? I just want something lightweigth and simple

Comment: No you don't have to, it's just easier as they handle all the grease work for you so you can focus on your application.

Comment: +1 for some good pointers in this answer, though it may be overkill for a lot of applications.